# Put Linq .ToList() to datatable

Tags: c#, linq

I want the data of this statement into dictionary/datatable.

```
            var distinctValues = datatable.AsEnumerable()
              .Select(row => new
              {
                  Employee = row.Field<string>("Employee")
              })
              .Distinct()
              .ToList();
```

Please help, how can i convert the distinctValues in datatable?

Update:

If anybody know a better way to find distinct values, then please suggest. I want to pass this in a c# functions and i cannot pass them as var.

Comment: Why cant you use var? It should be cast as IList<Entity> according to your sample?  All your method signature would have to look like is Method(IList<Entity> distinctValues){}...

Comment: @nakchak The result will be a `List<{anonymous type}>`.  `Entity` is a _property_, not a _class_.

Comment: good point, that said why bother with the anon class at all if all it has is a single string property?

Comment: Everything is so complicated. Can't anybody suggest a simple and easy way to find distinct values and store them in a datatable.

Answer (score 2):

Check the [CopyToDataTable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx) extension method.

Edit:
Changed to match Servy's comment.

Comment: That only works for sequences of data rows.  [This other CopyToDataTable method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx) is what's needed to create one from any arbitrary sequence.  Either that or you'll need to modify the query such that it keeps the data rows.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to be able to get the distinct items from a sequence, based on a selector, but keeping the items from the original sequence rather than the results of the selector.  This is commonly named `DistinctBy`.  [MoreLinq has an implementation](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs?r=d4396b9ff63932be0ab07c36452a481d20f96307), which (with minor modifications) is:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    return source.DistinctBy(keySelector, null);
}

public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
{
    return DistinctByImpl(source, keySelector, comparer);
}

private static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctByImpl<TSource, TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
{
    HashSet<TKey> knownKeys = new HashSet<TKey>(comparer);
    foreach (TSource element in source)
    {
        if (knownKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
        {
            yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```

Using that, along with the [CopyToDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx) method to convert the rows back into a table, you can now do:

```
var distinctTable = datatable.AsEnumerable()
    .DistinctBy(row => row.Field<string>("Employee"))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Getting this error: get this error: 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>' does not contain a definition for 'DistinctBy' and no extension method 'DistinctBy' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)                                                         What should i need to add more?

Comment: @user1254053 You need the function that I provided in this answer; it is the implementation of `DistinctBy`.

Answer (score 0):

Try an extention method like this, maybe it's not so fast, but it's really simple:

```
public DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this List<T> items)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
            //Get all the properties
            PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
            {
                //Setting column names as Property names
                dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
            }
             foreach (T item in items)
            {
                var values = new object[Props.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
                {
                    //inserting property values to datatable rows
                    values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
                }
                dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
            }
             //put a breakpoint here and check datatable
            return dataTable;
        }
```